# How to get number of objects being watched below 2000 of angular UI grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

How to implement below mentioned points to improve performance of UI grid

- Avoid using ng-repeat (sort it before insertions)
- Use of one-time bindings (:: syntax)

Is there a way by which i can reduce $watches count in UI grid component?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like below to reduce the watchers count in application :

```
<table border="solid 1px">
    <tr ng-repeat="dept in ::departments">
    <td>{{::dept.name}}</td>
    <td>{{::dept.title}}</td>
    <td>{{::dept.retention}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, i want to use one time binding. Can you please tell, how we can implement it in UI grid http://ui-grid.info/